# MapView with button on bottom

Tags: android

I'm trying to place a button at the bottom of my layout. Here's what I did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:apiKey="mykey"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This works well enough, but the button is overlayed on top of the mapview. I want the mapview to end right on top of the button. I thought I could just set the mapview to layout_height="wrap_content" but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to add this to my MapView:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Comment: Since you are using RelativeLayout that would be correct. Your initial fix would work for LinearLayout and such

Answer (score 1):

jst add the code : 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"